# Different server addresses and client address

Tags: java, sockets, connection, ip-address

Server has couple of ip addresses (let say 1 and 2)

```
iface eth0 inet static
  address         1.1.1.1
  netmask         255.255.255.0
  addresses-test      1.1.1.2/32
```

Address 1 is default and all applications use it. How can I change connection address for my applicaton? For example, app1 connects to serverX and serverX see client  address 1, app2 connects to serverX and see client address 2.

Is it possible at least theoretically? I trying to find java API, but any other working way would be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the socket to a specific local address before connecting, see http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#bind(java.net.SocketAddress).